# Macro tasks queue VS Callback queue

Tags: javascript, promise, callback

I need to know if there is a difference between the 2 of them

i tried searching the web and everybody talks about micro vs callback queue which is obvious. but no one made it clear that callback queue and macro queue are the same or different

Comment: Was this not answered at your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74844151/macro-tasks-queue-vs-callback-queue)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of (or at least closely related to) [What is the difference between callback queue and event queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67554089/1048572)

Answer (score 0):

A task queue is a queue of tasks to run. Each task usually consists of steps like "execute callback x with arguments y", that's why it's also sometimes called a "callback queue", which would be a queue of functions to execute (generally without arguments). More or less they're the same thing, at least you can implement one using the other, which makes them equivalent.